# Why is that bootbox.alert in success function won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my `Delete function`

```
$("#Delete").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete order?","No","Yes",function(r){
    if(r) {
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "POST",
            async : false,
            data : {
                empgrocmstID:1,
                todo:"Delete"
            },
        success:function(result){
            bootbox.alert("Order Deleted",function(){
                $("#Delete").attr("disabled", true);
            });
            updateTable();
            }
        });   
    } else {

    }
    });
});
```

This is my `Delete button`

```
<button id="Delete" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Delete Order</button>
```

This is my PHP query for the `Delete`

```
case "Delete":
    $Deletequery = "DELETE FROM tb_empgroc_master WHERE empgrocmstID='id'";
    mysql_query($Deletequery, $con);
break;
```

The problem is that `bootbox.alert` won't work but `bootbox.confirm` shows. Only if I delete the code `url:url,` the `bootbox.alert` shows. What's wrong with the `url:url,` in ajax?
This is my `table form` in html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" action="../process/PHP_groceryOnlineReleasing.php" method="POST">
<table class="tablesorter table table-bordered table-condensed" id="cLoanOut" style="table-layout: fixed;">
```

This is my script for the `url` that calls the `url form`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var $table = $('#cLoanOut'),$tbody = $('#cLoanOut tbody'), url = $('#main-form').attr('action'), currentSort;
</script>
```

And the script for posting the `url`

```
function updateTable(){
    $.post(url,{todo:"display"},function(response){
        $('.progress').hide();
        $tbody.html(response);
        $table.trigger('update');
    },'html');
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is the result from `console.log(result)`?

Comment: is `url` defined somewhere? if you don't remove `url` do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: if I dont remove url, POST http://localhost//emcis_coopmain//process//PHP_groceryOnlineReleasing 404 (Not Found) and when I remove the url , GET http://localhost/js/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js 404 (Not Found) @RamisWachtler